# Combining Selects with two different Group Bys in same query

Tags: mysql

I just have one table with 4 columns (1 is primary key- not used here)

Col1: Year

Col2: Cust_ID

Col3: Units

I want to combine these two queries to generate one output, however the different group by's are required.

select Cust_ID,year,sum(Units) from table
group by cust_ID;

select cust_id,year,Units from table
group by cust_id,year;

Independently they both work.

When I try to combine them and GROUP BY cust_id,year the sum(units)
only gets the sum of the specific year (which is correct for the non-sum query), whereas i need the sum of ALL YEARS
where the cust_id is the same.

Comment: Add some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what you want to achieve.

If you want just cust_id and sum of units for all years:
SELECT cust_id,SUM(units) FROM table GROUP BY cust_id

If you want cust_id and year plus sum of all years for customer:

SELECT t1.cust_id,t1.year,SUM(t1.units) unitsForYear,(SELECT SUM(t2.units) FROM table t2 WHERE t1.cust_id = t2.cust_id) unitsForAllYears
FROM table t1 GROUP BY cust_id,year